# Why does my function call doesn't calls the respective function?

Tags: shell, bigdata

I'm expecting the code to call the respective function based on the condition

```
# Call Decrypt password function
echo "country is:"$2
if [ $2 == MT ]
then
  DecryptPassword()
  InsertSCSTAR_AMH
  exit 0;
fi

if [ $2 == MX ]
then
InsertSCSTAR_AMH
fi
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). As it is at the moment, it is virtually unreadible.

Comment: I don't really see how this is related to big data. Seems like a shell script question, but you haven't even specified which one

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your code is running under some shell that does not like this syntax. In my test, zsh and csh does not work but bash or sh works. To make sure you are using bash for example, find out the path of bash by typing

```
which bash
```

And if the response is say /usr/bin/bash then add this as the very first like of your script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

Note it has to be the first line and notice no spaces above.
Make sure your script has execute permission for you - you probably have that already.